# How to generate individual XSD files using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I have a web service with several methods, each method has its own response and request (POJO classes).

I want to distribute XSD files to my users, so I have decided to use JAXB to generate the schema files.

My problem is that I want to have individual files (one per service)!!

I have tried JAXB but all I get is a big XSD with all my objects

Comment: What command line did you try? There's an option to specifify just the Java files you need (in this case rq/rs java) and schemagen should bring in whatever else it needs, nothing else.

Comment: The command is :schemagen ClassA.java ClassB.java ClassC.java package-info.java ... The problem is that I have to add the task to my build lifecycle which turns the problem even harder

Comment: So you're saying that with this command you're still getting unwanted stuff? Or that is not easy to integrate this command line into your build?

Comment: Both of them, I want to run a command like that but I need individual XSD files (not a massive XSD) and I need something that I can integrate in my build scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your Web Sevice with JAX-WS, `wsdl` tells everything what each client's needs and scopes.

Anyway.. say JAX-RS?

You can generate small scope of XSDs for each class or some classes with JAXBContext#generateSchema

```
public void generateSchema(final Class<?> classesToBeBound,
                           final OutputStream schemaStream)
    throws JAXBException, IOException {

    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classesToBeBound);

    context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {
        public Result createOutput(final String namespaceUri,
                                   final String suggestedFileName)
            throws IOException {

            return new StreamResult(schemaStream) {
                @Override
                public String getSystemId() {
                    return suggestedFileName;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```